# Comando \c connect pede senha que eu não criei [Postgres]

Tags: postgresql, psql

Olá, criei a tabela

```
controle_compras
```

e deu tudo certo. Inseri itens conforme indicado na aula, mas só a a título de exercício, parti para a criação de outra tabela apenas para treinar os comandos. Mas quando resolvi fazer o \c connect controle_compras; aparece assim:

```
postgres=# \c connect controle_compras;
Senha para usuário controle_compras:
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "controle_compras"
Conexão anterior mantida
postgres=#
```

O problema é que em nenhum momento, eu setei senha para esse BD. Até tentei usar a senha geral que conecta ao SGBD mas não funcionou. Sei que provavelmente o erro deve ser uma besteira. Mas sou bem iniciante.qu

Comment: No psql o comando para conexão com um banco de dados é ou \c ou \connect. No seu caso ele assumiu que o dbname é connect e controle_compras o username. Consulte a ajuda do psql.

Answer (score 0):

resolvido. Retirei o connect. Então para fazer a conexão com o db controle_compras usei `\c controle_compras;`